# hierarchical query, accounts tree

Tags: sql, oracle

I got stuck with hierarchical query to search parent or child accounts, Generally let's assume one example:

Table account:

```
Account    Parent
217518     217518 or null
304229     217518
424590     217518
378327     217518
491504     378327
234123     491504
```

So hierarchy looks:

[image]

Now, I got table "SHOW_PARENT_CHILD_ACC" where I will insert account which I would like to show. (I need to use it in hierachical query)

Insert into Show_parent_child_acc(acc) values (304229).

Query should return all the account id so:

```
304229     
424590     
378327 
217518    
491504     
234123
```

Same when I will
insert into show_parent_cild_acc(acc) values (234123)

Query should return all the account id so:

```
304229     
424590     
378327 
217518    
491504     
234123
```

In other words, no matter which account (parent/child or child of the child) I will insert into show_parent_child_acc table.Query should return whole account hierarchy

For now I have smth like:

```
WITH acc_to_delete( ID ) AS (
                            select case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end from account where accountid in                                          
                                 (select acc from show_parent_child_acc) 
                          )
                          SELECT accountid id_acc,case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end parentaccount
                          FROM   account p
                          START WITH
                           EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
                                    FROM   acc_to_delete w
                                    WHERE  p.accountid = w.ID
                                    )
                          CONNECT BY accountid = PRIOR parentaccount
                          union
                          SELECT accountid id_acc,case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end parentaccount
                          FROM   account p
                          START WITH
                          EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
                                    FROM   acc_to_delete w
                                    WHERE  p.accountid = w.ID
                                    )
                          CONNECT BY PRIOR accountid = parentaccount
```

But it doesn't works as expected (it works fine where I put into SHOW_PARENT_CHILD_ACC : 217518.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with finding root id (subquery "root") and then create typical hierarchy:

```
with 
  tmp as (select acc from show_parent_child_acc ),
  root as (
    select max(acnt) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl) root
      from (
        select nvl(parentaccount, accountid) acnt, level lvl  
          from account a cross join tmp
          connect by nocycle prior parentaccount = accountid
          start with accountid = acc or parentaccount = acc ))
select accountid from account cross join root
  connect by nocycle prior accountid = parentaccount
  start with parentaccount = root.root
union select root from root
```

Test data and output:

```
create table account (accountid number(8), parentaccount number(8));
insert into account values (217518, 217518);
insert into account values (304229, 217518);
insert into account values (424590, 217518);
insert into account values (378327, 217518);
insert into account values (491504, 378327);
insert into account values (234123, 491504);
create table show_parent_child_acc (acc number(8));
insert into show_parent_child_acc values (234123);

AccountID
---------
   217518
   234123
   304229
   378327
   424590
   491504
```

Comment: Glad I could help. The problem here was that root values were not clearly defined. In your examples 217518 could not exist at all **or** have the same parent as id **or** have null parent. I tried to write query that deals with all cases, this is why `nocycle` appears.
_I zawsze to fajnie pomóc rodakowi, pozdrawiam_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Modified original query further as below.

```
WITH acc_to_delete( ID ) AS (
                        select case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end from account where accountid in                                          
                             (select acc from show_parent_child_acc) 
                      )                      
SELECT DISTINCT accountid id_acc, case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end parentaccount 
FROM account START WITH parentaccount in
(                          
    SELECT case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end parentaccount
    FROM   account p 
    START WITH
    EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
            FROM   acc_to_delete w
            WHERE  p.accountid = w.ID
        )
    CONNECT BY nocycle accountid = PRIOR parentaccount 
    UNION
    SELECT case when parentaccount is null then accountid else parentaccount end parentaccount
    FROM   account p 
    START WITH
    EXISTS( SELECT 'X'
            FROM   acc_to_delete w
            WHERE  p.accountid = w.ID
            )
    CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR accountid =  parentaccount
) 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE parentaccount = PRIOR accountid
```

Mainly it collects all corresponding parents and then get their children.